# Replacing value of static const char array

Tags: c++, c

I was writing unit tests and I needed to override the path in "static const char[] path = "/some/hardcoded/path" to something else. Whats the best way to do it. I think it can be done by LD_PRELOAD but it requires me to create another library. Is there any other easy way to do this?

Comment: It's `const`. Don't do this. If you have some functional requirement, then contact the author and make your case. Otherwise, deal with it. Sorry.

Comment: I concur. Somebody putting a hard coded path should be shot!

Answer (score 3):

Comment it out and add in your own path.

You don't want to un-`const` something.

If you need, put it into a preprocessor block:

```
#ifndef __UNIT_TEST
   static const char[] path = "/some/hardcoded/path";
#else
   static const char[] path = "/some_other/hardcoded/path";
#endif
```

Then it won't fail on the original programmer's system either.

Answer (score 1):

Is hiding it an option?  Like this:

```
static const char* path = "...";

void f()
{
#if UNIT_TESTING
   static const char* path = "Ha!";
#endif
   cout << path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of such a string at execution time is undefined behavior. On many systems, the implementation-defined response is to drop core (segmentation fault). That said, a formerly common paradigm in many UNIX applications was to have hard-coded but configurable pathnames. The name is set at compile time rather than execution time:

```
static const char * path = SOME_PREPROCESSOR_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be hacky, and have no way to change the source directly, it is possible to use mprotect() on Unix and VirtualProtect() on Win32 to make the page of that array readable/writable/executable as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

If your system supports it, make the hard coded file a symbolic link to what you want.  Something like `ln -T /where/i/want/file /some/hardcoded/path/file`